# Dropbox asks me for password and resync on DropBox start

Tags: macos, sync, dropbox

Everytime I start the Dropbox app (version 2.10.41) on Mac OS X (version 10.9.5) it asks me to log in and after login it starts to sync and tells me that my computer is linked successfully.

This password enter and waiting for it to sync up is fairly annoying, so does anybody know what I can do, so that Dropbox remembers that my computer is linked?

I have tried several things without success:

1. I have tried the permission fix on https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/72 (Under `For our advanced user`)
2. I have tried deleting `/Application/Dropbox` and reinstalled Dropbox
3. I have tried deleting `~/.drop_box` and reinstalled Dropbox